# Syntax Error, Unexpected ',' in Rails Project using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm a really new coder, especially to rails. Any help much appreciated.

My user.db file is throwing up an exception. I'm trying to follow a tutorial setting up Devise and doing so requires adding :first_name :last_name and :profile_name to the attr_accessible line in my user.rb file.

But when I run my local server I get an exception.

The exact error is:

```
/Users/Trevor/Documents/RailsProjects/treebook/app/models/user.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
                  :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name
```

I don't know what will help, so here's the entire trace (I get this by removing the guilty code, starting the server, adding the code back, and the refreshing the browser.)

The full trace is:

```
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:554:in `get'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:588:in `constantize'
devise (2.1.2) lib/devise.rb:256:in `get'
devise (2.1.2) lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in `to'
devise (2.1.2) app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:28:in `resource_class'
devise (2.1.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:81:in `build_resource'
devise (2.1.2) app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `new'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__3399957301248495580__process_action__4505264721263125690__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1758572527611354071__call__3978322130075018224__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/Trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/Trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/Trevor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: show the full code of your user.rb model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your exact syntax error is, but the correct declaration is:

```
class User
    attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :profile_name
end
```